# DoCmd.RunSQL mySql got Run-time error '3464'

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have this simple code of vba access to update product in the database. But when I debug, it stops at the DoCmd statement and got run-time error. I've made research about this kind of error and code, and had changed the code but still caused an error. Below is my simple code to update the product value.

```
Sub UpdateProduct()

     Dim mySql As String

     mySql = "UPDATE " & Forms!UPDATE_PRODUCT!cbxLensType _
           & " SET LOT_NO = " & Forms!UPDATE_PRODUCT!txtLotNo _
           & " WHERE EAN_CODE = " & Forms!UPDATE_PRODUCT!txtEan & ";"
     DoCmd.RunSQL mySql

End Sub
```

Could you help me to explain what is the problem to my code? Is it because of the update syntax? 
Thanks in advance.

**New to access vba

Comment: Just to be clear, **Forms!UPDATE_PRODUCT!cbxLensType** returns the name of the table and that EAN_CODE is Numeric type?

Comment: @PaulFrancis: Yes, the Forms!UPDATE_PRODUCT!cbxLensType returns the table name and the EAN_CODE is text type in the database field. So, what's the problem actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since EAN_CODE is Text type you need to enclose it inside single quotes.

```
Sub UpdateProduct()
    Dim mySql As String

    mySql = "UPDATE [" & Forms!UPDATE_PRODUCT!cbxLensType _
           & "] SET LOT_NO = " & Forms!UPDATE_PRODUCT!txtLotNo _
           & " WHERE EAN_CODE = '" & Forms!UPDATE_PRODUCT!txtEan & "';"

    DoCmd.RunSQL mySql

End Sub
```

If `LOT_NO` is also a Text type, make sure that it is also enclosed in Single quotes.